# Cambiar flex-grow con jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Buenas tardes estoy trabajando con `flex-grow`. Me gustaría que según entro en cada uno de los módulos ese coja un flex-grow de 10 y todos los demás se pongan en 3, hasta que no entro en otro ese se mantiene con 10.

En mi cambeza esta añadir una clase en el que entro y borrarla a la vez en los demás, pero no consigo hacerlo

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.pafe-image-accordion__item', function() {
    //console.log("entra");
    $( this ).addClass( "acordeon10" );
    $(".pafe-image-accordion__item").removeClass( "acordeon10" );
});
```

```css
.pafe-image-accordion {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 702px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.pafe-image-accordion__item {
    transition-duration: .5s;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
    font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}
.pafe-image-accordion__item>img {
    max-width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%!important;
}
.acordeon3 {
    flex-grow: 3;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);
}
.acordeon10 {
    flex-grow: 10;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="bannerLocalizaciones">
    <div class="pafe-image-accordion">
        <div class="pafe-image-accordion__item acordeon3">
            <img src="http://rustic.klondigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/AmberleyCastle-3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="pafe-image-accordion__item acordeon10">
            <img src="http://rustic.klondigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/AmberleyCastle-3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="pafe-image-accordion__item acordeon3">
            <img src="http://rustic.klondigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/AmberleyCastle-3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="pafe-image-accordion__item acordeon3">
            <img src="http://rustic.klondigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/AmberleyCastle-3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="pafe-image-accordion__item acordeon3">
            <img src="http://rustic.klondigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/AmberleyCastle-3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es tu orden, primero añades la clase al div al que entra, y luego le quitas la clase a todos los div que la tienes. Si quitas primero la clase a todos los div que la tienen y luego añades la clase al div que está en onHover, funciona bien.

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.pafe-image-accordion__item', function() {
    //console.log("entra");
    //CAMBIO DE ORDEN
    $(".pafe-image-accordion__item").removeClass( "acordeon10" );
    $( this ).addClass( "acordeon10" );
});
```

```css
.pafe-image-accordion {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 702px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.pafe-image-accordion__item {
    transition-duration: .5s;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
    font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}
.pafe-image-accordion__item>img {
    max-width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%!important;
}
.acordeon3 {
    flex-grow: 3;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);
}
.acordeon10 {
    flex-grow: 10;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="bannerLocalizaciones">
    <div class="pafe-image-accordion">
        <div class="pafe-image-accordion__item acordeon3">
            <img src="http://rustic.klondigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/AmberleyCastle-3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="pafe-image-accordion__item acordeon10">
            <img src="http://rustic.klondigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/AmberleyCastle-3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="pafe-image-accordion__item acordeon3">
            <img src="http://rustic.klondigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/AmberleyCastle-3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="pafe-image-accordion__item acordeon3">
            <img src="http://rustic.klondigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/AmberleyCastle-3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="pafe-image-accordion__item acordeon3">
            <img src="http://rustic.klondigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/AmberleyCastle-3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono perfectamente!